# submit event not redirecting the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code displays images along with the products and got view details individually. once the 'View details' button is clicked its not redirecting to the new page. Hope issue with my function created....please view my code

```
   <?php
    session_start(); //start session
    include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ajax Shopping Cart</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
            $(".form-item").submit(function(e){
                var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
                window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(form_data);
                //button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text
                 e.preventDefault();
            });  
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
    <h3>Product list view</h3>
    </div>
    <?php
    //List products from database
    $results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code, product_image, product_price FROM products_list");
    //Display records from database
    $products_list =  '<ul class="products-wrp">';

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products_list .= <<<EOT
    <li>
    <form class="form-item">
    <h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
    <div><img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}"></div>
    <div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
    <div class="item-box">     
        <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
        <button type="submit">View details</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </li>
    EOT;

    }
    $products_list .= '</ul></div>';

    echo $products_list;
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should read this: [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Why are you putting all the form fields inside another URL parameter. It probably should be `"1stlink.php?" + form_data`

Comment: And why do you do this with a redirect? It's basically the same as using `<form method="get" action="1stlink.php">`

Comment: @Barmar could you please write an answer with respect to my mistakes, hope i am making un nececessary statements in my code

Comment: @barmar i am using inside form fields thinking that since url gets dynamic data as per the click of individual products it receives individual product code and it passes along with the URL..

Comment: Does `1stlink.php` use `parse_str($_GET['variable'])` to decode the URL parameter?

Comment: @Barmar yes it uses $_GETGET['variable']

Comment: In that case I think it should work the way you've written it.

Comment: Open Developer Tools to the Network tab and see what happens when this code is executed.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but maybe `e.preventDefault()` should be before `window.location`.

Comment: @Barmar i got the solution just a mistake with my braces put extra.. thanks for your concern

Comment: Using a good IDE will prevent most of those kinds of problems.

Comment: sure barmar.. thats good tip for ne

Answer (score -1):

Put this script at the bottom of the body as the last element.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".form-item").submit(function(e){
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
            window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(form_data);
            //button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text
             e.preventDefault();
        });  
});
```

Comment: Why does he need to put it at the bottom? Using `$(document).ready()` means it doesn't run until everything is loaded.